# How to setup a textarea with auto suggest from Dictionary

Tags: javascript

This Question is bit broad, I did enough research and asking here so that I can get at least some suggestions.

I am trying to set up auto complete textbox/textarea dictionary suggestions. I have tried to setup auto-complete from `JSON data from server` and I am able to do that.. But here my question is, Can I set up a textarea with auto suggest from dictionary words like when we are entering some text in Word processor. Is it possible through any API available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure you would have find many ways to achieve autocomplete on TextArea. To name a few

- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
- http://textextjs.com/

Both the framework and function are rich enough.

Coming on the dictionary API's

- http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=Sweet&sl=en&tl=en 
  Undocumented API of google, returns [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

API page for altervista

- http://thesaurus.altervista.org/testjs

Few others are

- http://words.bighugelabs.com/api.php
- http://developer.dictionary.com/products
- https://webster.cs.washington.edu/cse154/labs/ajax/urban.php?term=india
- http://www.wordreference.com/docs/api.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete). Here's some related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api). I can't find any official documentation to the Google `Search` Autocomplete API, thankfully someone already [did the research for us](http://blog.shreyaschand.com/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/). Follow instructions there, it shouldn't be too difficult to set-up (looks rather straight forward with both `JSON` and `XML` notated responses).

Comment: For anyone else coming here ~7 years later, the "did the research for us" link is now here: https://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you do have access to a JSON response from some server, you could use jQuery. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
$(function() {
  function log( message ) {
    $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
    $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
  }

  $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      log( ui.item ?
        "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't have any JSON object at my server side. I am looking for API like wordnik.com

Comment: And can't you use the wordnik api in your server? Make sure you've got an url to perform the AJAX call (you can use http://developer.wordnik.com/ in your server) and then use the jQuery call in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery with your dictionary function....
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

you can download it from here

http://jquery.com/download/