# How to create dictionary app with suggested list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dictionary, dart

I've already researched this section and i know that api google dictionary is deprecated .
I've got recommend this free api: https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/ .
But the problem this is a stable api and i want to ask about suggestion list in api response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Datamuse](https://www.datamuse.com/api/) API. Here is a [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-an-autocomplete-feature-in-flutter-bea21d6b1847) I found on how to implement it in flutter. Also check out this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575604/how-to-setup-a-textarea-with-auto-suggest-from-dictionary) which lists more API's related to this.

Comment: oh , it's kinda interesting article . Many thanks