# how to integrate Google auto suggest in Adobe flex/flash

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete, google-api

I would like to integrate google auto text suggest in adobe flex. I could not found out which url should I use to do this. please let me know is there any api from google to do this.

[image]

Thanks all

Comment: Do you want to get specific Google Data?  Or do you just want the Auto Suggest style functionality?  If you just need the functionality, I recommend our AutoComplete component: https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&ProductID=19

Comment: but for this component from where u feed data!! see i have added image

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api

Comment: @niran With the Flextras component (and most other Flex AutoComplete implementations out there) you set the data using the dataProvider property.  It does not load data automatically.

Comment: I have developed my own flex component. here main issue is feeding and fetching data which actually comes from google