# Google Search Bar on website

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a search bar on my website that allows the user to type their search and it will go to the google search engine.

It works fine.

My question is how can I make it have the google auto recommendations come up. For example, If someone types "BAS..." into a regular search in Google.com... Basketball will come up along with other reccommendations. How can I add that to my little search bar on my site?

http://jsfiddle.net/EeRgp/

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: You can do this if you use the custom search service. https://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2631081&topic=2662726&ctx=topic

Comment: There was a similar earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api but the answers seem to be outdated now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google "provides" an auto-complete JSONP API:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        client: "chrome",
        q: "Query"
    }
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

`data` is the auto complete data.
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/MWvjx/

A complete working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8FTCG/

---

[image]

Seems like you can even use it as a mini calculator. :)

---

This API returns info further than just text. It also contains the type of every item, title (if it is a link), and relevance index.

---

PS: Sorry if you are not familiar with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). But when it comes to XHR and AJAX, jQuery is like an essential. It's like a life saver!

Comment: Derek your updated JS Fiddle works great. How can we take off the extra part of the sugguestions.. like if you type in G it says Google (query)

Comment: @user2626744 - What do you mean "extra part"? Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eHwwv/

Answer (score 0):

If you load the JavaScript console in your browser you will see this error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com/search?q=Google does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

In short, Google is preventing you form using it's engine in this way.  Fortuanly they provide a clean alternative: [Custom Search Engine](https://www.google.com/cse/)