# How do I add the stock Google search to my own website **with auto-complete**?

Tags: javascript, google-api, igoogle

I am not asking about Site Search. I am wondering how to include a Google search box that searches the whole internet (not limited to a single site like Site Search would be) that also uses the same autocomplete behavior you see on Google.com.

Some of you may remember iGoogle, which was Google's web portal which I used and loved for years until they shut it down last year. I'm making my own iGoogle replacement. I can easily enough add a textbox up top to do the search, but what I'm having trouble reproducing is the JavaScript autocomplete behavior that you get with regular Google.com.

So starting with this:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" value="" />
</form>
```

How do I get it to do auto-complete?

Comment: I remember iGoogle. I wasn't a big fan of it, though I did like Google Reader. Good idea though, but you are taking on a rather big task! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use some server side scripting and try to implement a solution based on suggested queries API. More can be found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api)

On the client side try make an AJAx call as the user types to the textfield. As for the autocomplete functionality, I have used jQuery UI's plugin and it seems to work pretty great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631081

```
On the Custom Search home page ( https://www.google.com/cse/all ), click the search engine you want.
Click Search features, and then click the Autocomplete tab.
Switch Enable autocomplete to ON.
```

Comment: That's site search, which I stated in the question is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept Theodore's answer as correct simply because he led me on the right path; though to be honest, he really didn't give me much and I really came up with the solution on my own here.

I discovered that if you query this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/s?tch=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=search+term+goes+here&cp=21
```

Where `q` is your search term and `cp` is the position of the cursor as you're typing, that will return a JSON response which can be parsed and converted into something usable, then integrated with jQuery UI. (Basically I just wrote a short little PHP script on my own server which opens that URL using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).) No guarantee on how long that will work though, as it seems very unofficial.

I also ended up using the [jQuery UI Autocomplete HTML extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/tree/master/src/autocomplete) by Scott González, because the data Google passes back has `<b>` tags in it already, so that worked quite well.