# How to use Google suggested queries API in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, search-suggestion

Is there a way to use [Google suggested queries API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api) in Google Apps Script? If the answer is no, what is be best alternative? My aim is to perform spell correction and semantic aproximation for poor queries keywords of values in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the UrlFetchApp to get the data.

```
  var query = "give me suggestions"
  var stringResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=" + encodeURIComponent(query)).getContentText();
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(stringResponse);
  var searchString = parsedResponse[0];
  Logger.log("search string: " + searchString);
  var suggestions = parsedResponse[1];
  for (var i=0; i<suggestions.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("Suggestion: " + suggestions[i]);
  }
```