# Can I get Google top 10 autocomplete words in Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, google-api, httprequest

Is it possible to get the top 10 autocomplete words from google search? 
I need this to work like this example:
I type a word in google search, example:`ear` and google is returning suggestions so you can complete your query, example returning words: `ear wax, ear piercing, ear infection` etc.. So I would like to get the top 10 returning words from google in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no official documented API for what you are trying to do. However, a call to this `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=ear` will output your expected words.

After some searching, [this](http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/) blogpost explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many posts about how to access the Google search API to get autocomplete candidates. For example just by googling I found [Google Search autocomplete API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api).

I don't see how your question is really specific to either Android or Java though. If you don't know how to make a HTTP request from Android, then I think that should be a separate question (which, honestly you will also find by searching old questions).