# Does google allow businesses to use "Did you Mean" feature as an api?? I would like to use it but I am not getting anything

Tags: google-api, search-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-search-api, google-search-platform

I want to use Google API for Did you mean feature. So basically I want to write a piece of code, which sends a word to Google search and either Google finds the exact hits or gives a "DID YOU MEAN" reply which i would use.

Is it made available? Tried finding it but couldn't find.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: i am not asking for a recommendation or a comparison or to find the Library but means to access the API. I am not able to access this API and need help in finding documentation (if any).Fits perfectly i suppose in the stackoverflow.

Comment: If that is the case then you should re-phrase your question according to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: bizarre this was downvoted. this is just a straightforward question, with a straightforward yes/no/heres my hack solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I invested some time and this what I've found

1/ You should have your custom search engine

https://cse.google.com

2/ Configure it to search all webs

https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631040?hl=en

3/ Make query to that engine following the document

**https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest**

Spelling / Did you mean repairs if possible can be found in "spelling" section. (Irrelevant sections removed) . Fox ex: I searched for "devart" here

```js
{
  "kind": "customsearch#search",
  "url": {
    },
  "queries": {
    "request": [
      
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    
  },
  "searchInformation": {
    
  },
  "spelling": {
    "correctedQuery": "deviantart",
    "htmlCorrectedQuery": "<b><i>deviantart</i></b>"
  },
  "items": [
    
  ]
}
```

I had the same question and its downvoted also while they are allowing these questions on the site. You may want to read about the auto-complete apis here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061449/google-auto-correct-api

[Google Search autocomplete API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api)

Comment: this is a nice hack, though limited to the 100 requests per day. did you ever find a way around this without doing a direct scrape?