# Google traslate API request sample for did you mean

Tags: google-api, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

When I select a input language and type some word (as it pronounce). It gives a 'Did you mean' options. How can I get this option as a response from Google cloud translate API?

[image]

Please take a look on below image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I29AP.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does google allow businesses to use "Did you Mean" feature as an api?? I would like to use it but I am not getting anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260655/does-google-allow-businesses-to-use-did-you-mean-feature-as-an-api-i-would-l)

Comment: Have you checked the documentation to see if its supported?

Answer (score 0):

Not for Google Translate, but you can use SerpApi Spell Check API. It extract Google "Did you mean?" from regular searches.

JSON should be structured that way. Assuming a search for "Coffeee":

```
  "search_information":
    { 
      ...
      "query_displayed": "coffeee",
      "spelling_fix": "coffee",
      "showing_results_for": "coffee"
    },
  ...
```

Documentation: https://serpapi.com/spell-check